# Debug Rule Project in Rule Designer

Tags: debugging, ibm-odm

I am new with ODM and I am trying debug a rule project in Rule Designer. I have created a debug configuration but when i start a debug mode nothing happens and stay [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzNmh.png). My project has 560 decision table, at least 600 rows. How can I out of this and debug my project ? If a pause the debug [the second picture is showed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxKj9.png)

Comment: You might want to edit the post and place the images in-line.

Comment: i can't put images yet because this is my first question at stack overflow, so I only can put link to images.

Comment: Which version of ODM are you using?

Comment: I am using 8.9 version